# How to handle if extra header file included?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Although I read questions similar to this one on SO, it still seems none of them provided a solution to my problem.

I have a header only utility, let's call it `hutil.h`, which contains a function, let's call it `hutil_func`. I created a small tool which has a header file, let's call it `tool.h`, and also a source file, let's call it `tool.c`. In `tool.c` I implemented some *"extra functionality"* which uses the `hutil_func` but I don't want to force the user, to use the `hutil.h` file if the user doesn't need its extra capabilities.

So lets assume the user has a `main.c` file, something like this:

```
// #include "hutil.h"           <-- How to handle if this is removed?
#include "tool.h"

int main(void)
{
    a_function_from_tool();  // <-- This can use hutil_func if hutil.h included
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I'm looking for a solution -- hopefully a macro to deal with this situation at compile time -- which will replace the `hutil_func` for example with an empty `#define hutil_func()` macro.

Thanks in advance!

---

***UPDATE1:***

`hutil.h` cannot be included into `tool.c`, since that's exactly what I want to avoid: if the user doesn't want to use `hutil.h`, then the user won't place it next to `tool.c`.

---

***UPDATE2:***

The function `hutil_func` is called inside `a_function_from_tool`.

Comment: You can simply place the prototype for your `hutil_func()` somewhere in the main.c, above where it is called.

Comment: Are you saying you *defined* a function in hutil.h?  If so, that's considered bad practice, this being one of the reasons why.  Regardless, including `hutil.h` shouldn't be a burden (unless your user has namting conflicts).

Comment: @JohnBode it is a `static inline` function

Comment: @ryyker but `hutil_func` is called inside `a_function_from_tool` not directly in `main.c`

Comment: @PeterVaro If it's in a header file, it should be a inline function, not static inline. If your compiler chooses not to make your function inline, you will have multiple copies of the function.

Comment: @PeterVaro - in that case, it appears Petesh has the start of a workable solution for you.  Keep in mind, if `hutil_func()` is called inside `a_function_from_tool()` then there is no way around have to define it somewhere.

Comment: @ryyker what do you mean by *"then there is no way around have to define it somewhere"*? it is defined in the `hutil.h`..

Comment: This just seems like a really bad design, if the functionality in one translation unit depends on what headers may or may not have been included in a completely different translation unit. If you want to have conditional compilation, why not just pass a constant to the compiler using `-D` for instance, and just have `tool.c` decide whether or not to `#include "hutil.h"` based on that, and you can forget about what's happening in `main.c`?

Comment: @ryyker I prototyped it in `tool.h` (as it is always included in our example), but then `tool.c` is complaining about `hutil_func` as it is undeclared. However if I prototype it in `tool.c` then how will the compiler know if `hutil.h` is included before `tool.h` or not in `main.c`? And since it is not only about one function, it would be a really ugly hack (and very unuser-friendly) if the user has to prototype it in `main.c` all the time.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths that sounds like a reasonable solution to me, can you express it in an answer? (if there is no other solution of course :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempting to do this using headers just seems like a bad design, and breaks modularity.

It's probably better to specify this as a compile time option. Your user can either use some kind of configure script, or just modify your makefile directly, and so if they choose to use this functionality, you end up calling something like:

```
gcc -o tool.o tool.c -c -DUSE_HUTILS
```

Then, in `tool.c` you can do something like:

```
#ifdef USE_HUTILS
#include "hutils.h"
#endif

...

int a_function_from_tools(void) {

    /*  Some code  */

#ifdef USE_HUTILS
    int n = hutil_func();
#else
    int n = get_n_some_other_way();
#endif

    return n;
}
```

That way, `tool.c` doesn't depend on, and doesn't care about, what was or was not included in `main.c`, which is how it should be.

If it can feasibly work for the specific code you're doing, you could avoid multiple conditional compilation blocks within the function itself by doing:

```
#ifdef USE_HUTILS
#include "hutils.h"
#else
#include "hutils_fake.h"
#endif
```

where `hutils_fake.h` contains the same interface as `hutils.h`, but that interface basically expands to nothing along the lines of what you refer to as "an empty `#define hutil_func()` macro." Alternatively, you could just do the check for `#ifdef USE_HUTILS` within `hutils.h` itself, and define real functionality if it's defined, and fake functionality if it isn't.

Doing something along these lines to provide different functionality which can optionally be compiled into or out of an application is fairly normal.

Comment: This is a bit trickier, than I expected, (since I wanted to use the header file inclusion as a toggle switch) but this solution provides a real compile-time-only solution.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** oops, misread the question. my bad.

The whole thing depends on if you've got *code* in `tool.h` or just declarations.

If you've got code, then you should be able to leverage something like the typical guard mechanism for the `hutil.h` file. In the `hutil.h` file you should have lines like:

```
#ifndef HUTIL_H_
#define HUTIL_H_

...

#endif
```

in `tool.h`, you guard the code that invokes the function from tool using:

```
#ifdef HUTIL_H_
   hutil_func();
#endif
```

This only works if you've got code in `tool.h` that can be guarded in this manner.

To accomplish this where `tool.h` is a header-only file, you're going to need some indirection.

Firstly you need to be able to tell the routine in `tool.h` what the function is that it should be able to use (this can be expanded for N entries using a struct pointer), so we modify the `tool.h` routine to take an extra parameter hutil_func, which is a pointer to a function which matches the calling pattern of the hutil_func, and give the routine a different name to the name we use when calling it e.g. `a_function_from_tool_internal`, so it looks like:

```
void a_function_from_tool_internal((void)(*utilfunc)(void), other_parameters);
```

in `tool.c`, where the code is being invoked, you check if utilfunc is `NULL`:

```
if (utilfunc != NULL)
    utilfunc();
```

Then we put the following in the `tool.h`:

```
#ifdef HUTIL_H_
#define a_function_from_tool(other_parameters) a_function_from_tool(hutil_func, other_parameters)
#else
#define a_function_from_tool(other_parameters) a_function_from_tool(0, other_parameters)
#endif
```

This sort of stuff is ugly, and falls down if you're using `#pragma once`, but it may allow you to get the kind of functionality you're looking for.

Comment: This could work, @Petesh, but it needs runtime checking, which I try to avoid... (`if (utilfunc != NULL)`), if possible, I'm looking for a compile time only solution.

Comment: True, but unless you're in a tight loop, it wouldn't account for much. TBH, Paul's answer is cleaner from a modularity point of view, I was just offering a potential solution using macros. If you wanted to optimize out the test, you could implement the routine twice once taking a parameter, once not taking it and call one or the other depending on the `#ifdef`.

Comment: Well, @Petesh, thank you very much for the effort, for me Paul's answer is cleaner too + it is a real compile-time-only solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can include hutil.h in tool.c. In that case hutil.h won't be visible in main.c.

Comment: And how exactly that solves my problem? That means, `tool.c` will always complain about `hutil.h`

Comment: No, because tool.c can see hutil.h.

Comment: But if `hutil-h` is not around it can't! And that's exactly I want to solve. If the user don'T want to use `hutil.h` then, the user won't include it, and also won't place it next to `tool.c`

Comment: let me get this clear: you want deliver a file that will be used even when the user deletes it? Take a second to think about that

Comment: Maybe you can put your headers in some fixed location and add it to the include paths, so people don't have to add them manually to their projects.

Comment: @Mabus That's a work-around but not the proper solution I'm looking for.

Comment: @bolov nope, I want a function to be called inside another function only if the other header file is included, but not to be called if it isn't

Comment: You can use macros and #ifdef or #if but I think it's a worse solution, and will only work if the headers are included in the proper order.

Comment: let's see that solution @Mabus, I don't mind if it always has to be included in this order: `hutil.h` -> `tool.h`

Comment: Define some macro in hutil.h, for example HUTIL_H_ and test in tool.h if the macro is defined, using #ifdef and #else to choose the function.

Comment: @Mabus I did that already, but since `tool.c` is compiled "alone" to be an object file, it has no knowledge of `tool.h`

Comment: What compiler are you using? Clang has the extension __has_include to check for a file before including it. I don't know if other compilers have it.

Comment: @Mabus I'm using clang, but want it to make compiler independent